# How do relational databases fetch the unindexed columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

My questions relate to the way relational DBs access the data, and the special case of using Index-Only-Scans, i.e. scans which check all 'where' conditions and fetch all return values from some index, without accessing the table itself.

1. Imagine we need to access some columns which are not in the index. We need to access them for one (or both) of two reasons: to compare with the 'where' clause and to fetch the column value as a result. How would the database act in this case: it would fetch the whole row, or it would fetch only the column it needs?
2. As a consequence of the first question emerges this one: does the number of columns to return in select query really matters if we are not using the Index-Only-Scan? I mean if we have to fetch or compare with 'where' clause some columns which are not indexed - does it really matter how many columns we return, or we can write "select * from ..." without any concerns in case DB fetches the whole row anyway?
3. When we use Index-Only-Scans we have to include all the columns the query deals with in one single index. If some column is included in another index - this will not burst the performance. Am I right?
4. I have read that MySQL InnoDB engine uses clustered indexes by default, i.e. all the rows in tables are physically sorted by some index. This means that searching that table using some secondary index would be less efficient, because after that search db has to make a second one over the primary index because in a clustered index db is not storing the rowId anymore. Am I right? If yes, why MySQL implements indexing in such a way, thus limiting the usage of secondary indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of these explanations probably go over stuff you already know, but the full detail may help future readers.

1. The server would most likely just get the rows that are needed.  However, this may be affected by how the data is stored.  For example, the InnoDB engine usually stores large data (like `TEXT`s and `BLOB`s off page, so those probably wouldn't be fetched if not needed.
2. I think I need some clarification here, so correct me if I'm missing something from your question.  First, it is better to only return the columns you needs and listing all of the columns instead of selecting `*` is faster.  As with #1, how much of a difference selecting other columns will make depends.  Selecting large columns (like `TEXT`s or `BLOB`s) is usually more expensive than small columns.
3. I'm not 100% sure what you mean here, but I think I can answer the question.  If you have a query like `SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM table WHERE c1 = 1 AND c2 = 2`, an index like `(c1,c2,c3)` would probably be optimal; all of columns that the query needs are in the index so the server doesn't need to look up the full data rows.  it does not matter if `c1`, `c2`, or `c3` are included in any other indexes.
4. In your question, you say that `a clustered index db is not storing the rowId anymore`, which isn't completely correct.

   Assuming that the `rowId` is a unique, probably numeric, identifier for the data:

   In a non-clustered database table, the all of the indexes connect some columns to the physical data location.  In the case of the primary index this would look like `rowId -> data location`.  A secondary index could look like `column 1 -> column 2 -> data location`.  To get any other data, the server then looks up the data based on the physical location.

   In a clustered table, the physical data basically is the primary index.  The primary index looks like `rowId -> data` and secondary indexes look like `column 1 -> column 2 -> rowId`.

   For a non-clustered table, the full look-up path would look like `rowId -> data location -> data` using a primary index and `column 1 -> column 2 -> data location -> data` for a secondary index.

   For a clustered table, it would look like `rowId -> data` for the primary index and `column 1 -> column 2 -> rowId -> data` for a secondary index.

   So to correct the quote at the beginning of this section, the only indexes that really "store" the `rowId` are secondary indexes on a clustered table.

   While secondary index look-ups on clustered tables are slower than on a non-clustered table, the difference is usually negligible if you're using a short primary key.  One of the main benefits of a clustered table is that primary index look-ups are faster, so if you're primarily using primary key look-ups, they are beneficial.

In response to KutaBeach's comments:

Fetching columns that aren't needed isn't helpful.  When the server needs to go the the data to get rows not in an index, it doesn't always fetch *all* of the data for that row.  Some storage configurations store some data apart from the main row since it may be very large and otherwise affect performance.  An example could be a `TEXT` column that is 65535 characters long for every row.  If the storage engine stores that data off page, getting data from rows is much faster if the `TEXT` column isn't needed.

It sounds like when you say `rowId`, you mean the physical address of the row, not a unique number assigned to each row. In this case, you are correct that only secondary indexes on a clustered table do not store the `rowId`; all other indexes store the `rowId`.  However, this is not because the data can or cannot move; the data in a table *can* move at any time, in which case the indexes get updated to reflect the move.  In MySQL, a `PRIMARY INDEX` is basically just the main index of a table.  It is pretty much the same as a `UNIQUE` index in that it forces values to be unique, with the only difference being that it is used as the main key for the table.  Non-clustered indexes do contain every `rowId`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, G-Nugget! Here are some clarifications of my questions: 2) why its better to fetch fewer columns by the query if DB will read the WHOLE row anyway? looks like for DB there are no difference.

Comment: 4) I cannot understand why you talk of "primary" index in non-clustered tables. I thought in these table one can create index on any column and there are no special treatment for any one of them. And these indexes usually connect some column value with rowId which can direct us to the place where the data resides. So they effectively store all rowIds. And only secondary indexes in clustered table do not store rowIds because rows may move in clustered tables. Am I right or wrong?